# Python - list concatenation

Tags: python, list

I have a question about list concatenation in Python, I have this piece of code:

```
def lista():
    word = sys.argv[1]
    l = []
    m = []
    for file_name in sys.argv[2:]:
        with open(file_name, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                l + [len(re.findall(word, line))] #doesn't work
                m.append(len(re.findall(word, line))) #works
    print l
    print m
    return l
```

when I run this function I always get empty list l, but there are elements in m, why l+[elem] doesen't work for me?

Comment: note: l is a bad variable name: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never assigning a new value to l. You should use assignment.
Try calling `l = l + [len(re.findall(word,line))]`

EDIT: another option is to use the += opertor: `l+=[len(re.findall(word,line))]`

Answer (score 3):

Because `l+[len(re.findall(word,line))]` is just adding the two list but throwing away the result. You probably want

```
l+=[len(re.findall(word,line))]
```

General observations:

- Your variable names are not according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Appending a list is costly and generally not pythonic. You can use a generator for this purpose.
- You should use a [with](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) statement with files, to ensure it is closed even if an exception occurs.

Here is the Program with suggested edits.

```
def lista():
    word=sys.argv[1]
    def search():
        for file_name in sys.argv[2:]:
            with open(file_name,"r") as fin:
                for line in fin:
                    yield len(re.findall(word,line))
    return [l for l in search()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you want to just use `l.append()` - what you are doing has the same effect, except it's less readable and slower.

```
python -m timeit -s "l=[]" "for i in range(1000):" "  l.append(i)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 106 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "l=[]" "for i in range(1000):" "  l += [i]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 124 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = l+[len(re.findall(word,line))] #works
```